# Codename One nested Sidemenu

Tags: codenameone, side-menu

I am trying to create a nested side menu for a CN1 application, similar to the one in the screenshot.

For the nested sidemenu to work, I image it has to stay open when the user presses a command of a dropdown list , so that he/ she can choose an option. 
But the CN1 sidemenu appears to close every time and I couldn't find a workaround.

One approach I was trying was to add an action event to the "hamburger menu ", but this doesn't seem to work.

```
    Button sideBtn = (Button)((BorderLayout)bar.getLayout()).getEast(); 
    sideBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
           Toolbar.setPermanentSideMenu(true);
       };
```

Neither does adding  Toolbar.setPermanentSideMenu(true) to any other button's action event.

Anther approach I have in mind is to add hidden buttons to the sidemenu and repaint the toolbar when the button is clicked, but this still does not keep the sidemenu open and seems to be not very direct.

Is there anything more straightforward? What would be the best approach?

Thanks in advance for any kind response. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setPermanentSideMenu` method is designed for tablets and not for what you are trying to do. Toggling it after the `init(Object)` method was invoked doesn't make sense and might break your app.

You didn't list how you added the button to the side menu but adding it using `addComponentToSideMenu(Component)` should work (notice I didn't use the version that accepts a `Command`).

Comment: Shai, is there a way to tap on the hamburger menu button and keep the sidemenu permanently open until the hamburger button is tapped again?

Comment: The side menu is closed by commands implicitly or by tapping outside of the side menu bounds. If you don't add a command and add a component instead it won't be closed